UUID not saved to database on user creation - workaround needed
When creating a new user, the UUID is generated automatically but is not being saved to the database (Digital Ocean). The UUID only appears in the database after manually re-saving the entry in the Strapi admin panel.
Has anyone encountered this issue before? If so, what workaround did you use to ensure the UUID is saved immediately upon user creation?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Why is digital ocean a star character of this question? Please specify the actual database software you are using, if you feel that's important. Also, please add how you are creating said new user if not using the strapi admin panel. And how do you know it is created but not saved?

Creating new user on the frontend (next.js). The uuid is not saved immediately in the database, hence why I mentioned Digitial Ocean (ubuntu) database. It is only saved once you re-save the entry in the strapi admin panel or refresh the uuid. This is not feasible with many users.

I suspect you have an issue with your Next.js code. If nothing else, your code can itself trigger the refresh. I suggest trying to atleast include the relevant portions of your code which the user interacts with and the portion calling the Strapi API. Making this minimum working example will be difficult, but necessary for someone to help. Also try to show what uuids are generated. It would be useful to know if you're seeing one UUID during creation on your frontend, and a different one when you open the entry in your admin panel.
